# Check field for identical number

Tags: php, select

I have this code: `<?php echo $pinDetails->id;?>`

this gives me a unique ID and displays it on my page.

I am trying to check whether this unique ID for one table is also in another table. Then if it is, show other data from that table.

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repin WHERE new_pin_id>$pinDetails->id") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
    Print "".$info['from_pin_id'].",".$info['new_pin_id']."";
} 
?>
```

To my understanding this should work fine but nothing appears. Do I have the syntax wrong?

Also, is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Please, **don't use `mysql_` functions**. They are officially deprecated, see [this topic on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). You should have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: change your query to `"SELECT * FROM repin WHERE new_pin_id>{$pinDetails->id}"`

Comment: and why it is `>` why not `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query like

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repin WHERE new_pin_id LIKE ".$pinDetails->id) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
    Print "".$info['from_pin_id'].",".$info['new_pin_id']."";
} 
?>
```

Comment: This gives the following error code:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.20042' at line 1.
"20042" is the ID number.

Comment: Perfect, works fine now. I'll examine my original code and the one you provided to see where I went wrong.

Comment: Q: How would I use the detail `".$info['from_pin_id']."` in another statement to grab info? Combine it with variables?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [*string interpolation*](http://php.net/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) by calling an object attribute directly.

Try this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repin WHERE new_pin_id>{$pinDetails->id}")
```

or even better with string concatenation:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repin WHERE new_pin_id>" . $pinDetails->id)
```