# Joining 2 statements to pull data from different tables

Tags: php, select

I have this code:

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repin WHERE new_pin_id LIKE ".$pinDetails->id) or         die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
Print "".$info['from_pin_id'].",".$info['new_pin_id']."";
} 
?>
```

Obtained thanks to this article: [Check field for identical number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754530/check-field-for-identical-number/19754605?noredirect=1#19754605)

I'm trying to use the detail I pulled: `".$info['from_pin_id']."` to get data from *another* table. I'm looking for the best way to do this.

I thought about making it a variable and then running a second statement within the same `<?php?>` which would look something like this:

```
Print "".$info['from_pin_id'].",".$info['new_pin_id']."";
} 
$newdata = "".$info['from_pin_id']."";
// new statement here.
?>
```

But 1. it won't work and 2. it looks messy.

What is the best way to achieve it?

FYI, what I need to do is use `".$info['from_pin_id']."` to match a field in another table where the data is the same ID, then pull more info based on the match.

Comment: Why do you surround your strings with `"".` and `.""`?

Comment: Can't you just use a normal SQL JOIN query?

Comment: Note that the code you posted here is NOT the working code from the other question you linked.

Comment: Thanks Johannes, edited Q.
@Barmar, I don't know, I thought this was the rule when using `Print`. I guess it is a habit that stuck. I have tried a JOIN but since I need the first statement to execute in order to get data to run in the second it won't work.

Comment: A join gets data from both tables at once. Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN if there might not be matching rows in the second table.

Comment: Thanks, I've completed it with the LEFT OUTER JOIN suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
"SELECT *
FROM repin r
LEFT JOIN otherTable o
ON o.someColumn = r.from_pin_id
WHERE r.new_pin_id LIKE '".$pinDetails->id."'"
```

Also, the argument to `LIKE` must be a string; you need to put quotes around it.